# C++ Values not retained in map on pass by reference

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, enums, shared-libraries

I'm using visual studio 2010 for my C++ project, and i'm facing a weird issue when passing maps between libraries. I have a `std::map<enum,string>` which is populated in A() in library Alib and passed to method B() in library Blib. When I try to access the passed map in B(), I only see 'error' in the VS debugger. But it shows correct size of the map

```
void Alib::A(){
   std::map<enum,string> lc_map;
   //Populate the map (with 24 pairs)
   Blib::B(lc_map);
   //work with 'lc_map' => key and values are not destroyed while working in B()
}

void Blib::B(const std::map<enum,string>& i_map){

   //i_map doesnt have the data that is passed. Size is same (24 pairs) but it shows 'error' entries in debugger.
}
```

**Things I tried:**

1. Change pass-by-reference to pass-by-value. **IT WORKS** (but map can get very large, so prefer const &)
2. Change the enum to int and see if that works fine. **IT WORKS**
3. Check if the enum types used by the libraries are of same/different version. Looks like they are of same version (but I don't trust my verification, which was clean rebuild. Is there a better way to check this?)

I ran out of options now. Do any of you have suggestions as to what might be causing this? Or how else can I debug the issue?

**Let me know if you need any additional details.**

**Edit 1:**

The enums that are used in map are declared in ALib and are 'exported'.

There seems to be some kind of loading issue. Because **I see the entries** in the passed map when I declare a local map with same signature in B(). I tried forward declaration but that didn't help. For now i'll go ahead with dummy local map. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: How are you checking the values in the map?

Comment: Are Alib and Blib classes or namespaces?

Comment: Why is the parameter for `B()` a const?

Comment: You can't pass a non-const value as a const parameter

Comment: @Brian you actually can. The `const` is just a promise that the parameter would not be mutated. What you **cannot** do is the opposite i.e. pass a constant value where no const-ness is expected. Anyway, such an example would not compile.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I tried reading values and didnt find them. Then I used Visual studio debugger to see all the values in map. It had 24 entries which said 'error'

Comment: @BrianGradin I want 'B' to only read the entries, hence the const. And non-const can be passed when expecting const, but not vice-versa

Comment: @theAlias yeah, I remember now.  My mistake

Comment: @MartinDrozdik BLib is namespace and B() is static function. Alib is one of the many classes inside the library